Intellij dart breakpoint in debug opens file second time as not writable
I develop an App in Flutter/Dart. As IDE I use IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2.
Since a few days, when ever debug reaches a breakpoint, it opens the file as a new Tab. But this is not writable. Also, the highlighting (partly) and 'Go To Declaration' as well as any editing does not work in the new Window, that makes development very annoying.
It only happens in my Dart/Flutter-Projects. I have a Typescript-Project as Server and there I have no problems. Other dart projects have the same issue.
What is going on here, and how do I fix that?
Thanks in advance.



It's a known issue in Flutter plug-in.
See this comment for the workaround.
Updating to the latest IDE/Flutter/Dart plug-in versions should also help.
